# Как складывать количество одинаковых товаров?

Tags: sql, база-данных, asp.net

sql express 2008, Asp.net webforms
Есть каталог. При нажатии на кнопку происходит запись в таблицу(корзина) товара.( в таблице Корзина есть поле "количество")
Если 2 раза нажать на кнопку, то в корзине появится 2 одинаковых товара по 1 шт.
Как сделать так, чтобы у одинаковых товаров увеличивалось их количество.

Кнопка которой записываю в бд.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    string ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\auto.mdf;Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    try
    {
        sqlCon.Open();

        var btn = (Button)sender;
        var dli = (DataListItem)btn.Parent;
        var Label2 = (Label)dli.FindControl("Label2");

        SqlCommand cmd_SQL = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Cart(ClientId,ProductId,Amount) VALUES (@ClientId,@ProductId,@Amount) ", sqlCon);
        cmd_SQL.Parameters.Add("@ClientId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
        cmd_SQL.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Label2.Text);
        cmd_SQL.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 1;

        cmd_SQL.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd_SQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //Response.Redirect("~/AdminAddCategory.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = "При соединении с БД произошла ошибка ";
        Label1.Text += ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlCon.Close();
    }
```

Строка вывода:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT Products.Image,Products.Name,Products.Description,Products.Price,Cart.Amount,Cart.ClientId,Cart.Id,SUM(Products.Price) FROM (Cart INNER JOIN Products ON Cart.ProductId = Products.id) WHERE (Cart.ClientId = @UserID) GROUP BY(Products.Id)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что в этой ситуации лучше использовать оператор [Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb510625(v=sql.120).aspx) вместо Insert.
Смотрите пример А.